# Sass @import using leading underscore

Tags: sass, partials

I understand that it is best practise to import SASS/SCSS partials without using the leading underscore; e.g.

```
@import 'normalize-scss/normalize'; 
// this imports ./normalize-scss/_normalize.scss
```

My question for nerdy completeness is, are there any consequences if the file is imported using the underscore?

```
@import 'normalize-scss/_normalize';
```

Comment: What happens when you have two files `__test.scss` and `_test.scss` and you `@import "_test"`

Comment: Related: [`Why put in front of the file name “_” or “_” in scss/css?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889962/why-put-in-front-of-the-file-name-or-in-scss-css).

Answer (score 29):

No.  If your file is _foo.scss, all of these imports have identical results as long as you don't have any ambiguous filenames (barring any side effects that might exist):

```
@import "foo";
@import "foo.scss";
@import "_foo";
@import "_foo.scss";
```

## Files with the same name but different extension

The only time an extension is necessary is if you have both _foo.scss and _foo.sass in the same search path.  You'll get the following error if you don't specify which one:

```
    error sass/test.scss (Line 7: It's not clear which file to import for '@import "test/bar"'.
Candidates:
  test/_bar.sass
  test/_bar.scss
Please delete or rename all but one of these files.
)
```

## Files with the same name, but one is prefixed with an underscore

If you have both foo.scss and _foo.scss, then foo.scss will take precedence.  If you want _foo.scss instead, you'll need to add the underscore to your import statement.

```
@import "test/_foo";
```

Sass will nag you with a warning every time you save no matter what your import statement looks like:

```
WARNING: In /path/to/test:
  There are multiple files that match the name "bar.scss":
    _bar.scss
    bar.scss
```

Comment: If by default the engine checks for `_foo.scss`, surely it would be fastest to use `@import "foo";`. Precious milliseconds!

Comment: What a very strange design decision - to treat the files as the same.

Comment: __Be aware:__ The SASS team is deprecating the use of `@import` in favor of `@use`. You can check it all out here: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import

Answer (score 22):

If you add an underscore to the start of the file name, Sass won’t compile it. So, if you don’t want `colors.scss` to compile to `colors.css`, name the file `_colors.scss` instead. Files named this way are called partials in Sass terminology.

More about import feature in Sass you can find [here](https://kolosek.com/sass-import/)

Comment: I think OP was asking more about during the import process. If you are compiling main.scss, and main has two imports ```foo.scss and _bar.scss``` these will be compiled in the same way. The sass compiler doesn't treat them differently in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`@import 'normalize-scss/_normalize';`

**This will simply treat the `_normalize.scss` file as not partial.**

So, if you want that file to be a partial file. then you add another underscore in the front of the actual file name. so the file name will be `__normalize.scss.`